# Authenticate using GitLab CLI (glab) with 1Password and 1Password CLI

Tags: gitlab, command-line-interface, 1password

I've followed all the steps from [1Password's documentation on setting up authentication with glab (GitLab CLI)](https://developer.1password.com/docs/cli/shell-plugins/gitlab/#get-help). Authentication works with commands like `glab repo list`, returning a list of repositories from my company's self-hosted GitLab server.

My problem is when I attempt to clone a repository over HTTPS from the server, it asks for login instead of using the personal access token I've saved in 1Password.

A disclaimer, we have decided to not setup SSH authentication, but rather use HTTPS via Personal Access Token exclusively.

It's easy to get around this problem by running `glab auth login` and providing the personal access token. However, this would mean the access token will be saved to `~/.config/glab-cli/config` file which would defeat the purpose of saving the personal access token in 1Password in the first place.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work without having to save the token in plain text, setup SSH access using 1Password, or osx keychain?

I'm running on macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was running into the issue above, I purposefully disabled osxkeychain by commenting out the following from ~/.gitconfig

```
[credential]
  helper = osxkeychain
```

This was to ensure that the previous personal access token I had were not being used for authentication.

However, I decided to experiment with osxkeychain and its relationship with 1Password and came across an interesting finding.

After [removing the personal access token from GitLab server web user interface](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#revoke-a-personal-access-token), and [clearing the credentials from osxkeychain](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain#deleting-your-credentials-via-the-command-line) by running

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase \
host=<self hosted gitlab host> \
protocol=https
```

I was still able to clone the repository using `glab repo clone <repo path>`.

This means that 1Password manages the osxkeychain entry for the personal access token under the hood to grant access without exposing the value in plain text in a file.

By re-enabling osxkeychain, I was able to get this working again.